# Prevent ng-cli to associate css with components

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli, systemjs

I'm trying to migrate an app which was using SystemJS to ng-cli environment. I don't want to change too much the structure of the app, and beside, I dont use a css file for each component, I want to keep it global.

When I run `ng serve`, I get the following error :

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/guest-sidebar.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/css/guest-sidebar.css' in '/project/src/app/components'
```

I'm pretty new on ng-cli or webpack, how do I tell ng-cli I dont want it to associate components with their css and handle it separatly ?

Comment: Divide module by chunks and associate then accordingly.

Comment: I dont understand. Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: What does it mean and how will it solve to problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this flag: `--inline-style` (alias: -is) default value: false

If you specify true then it will expect you to handle the styles "inline" and won't generate a separate css file.

Comment: Ah, perfect ! Thanks.